# bash multiline history with lithist option broken

Tags: bash, debian, centos, command-history

i used to enable lithist option, which make bash history store in multiline,
but one day, the lithist option not work.

enabling lithist mean you can store multiline in one history entry.
if you type some command enclosed by bracket:

```bsh
~:$ (
> echo hey
> echo bye
> )
hey
bye
```

then press `ctrl-p` , you will see this:

```bsh
~:$ (
echo hey
echo bye
)
```

in my bad day that lithist broken,
one will see multiline splitted into multiple entry

```bsh
# press ctrl-p
~:$ )
# press ctrl-p again
~:$ echo bye
```

this problem occur a few times before. it is usually happend because the size of `~/.bash_history` exceed the variable `HISTFILESIZE` , and bash truncate the `~/.bash_history`, which make format of history file broken.
i used to remove some beginning line of history file,  then restart the shell,
and history would recovery.

however, this time it does not recover even
after i remove the whole history file.

my config:

```
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=8000
shopt -s cmdhist lithist
```

with lithist working, the output of command `history`
should look like to following:

```
 4519* 2019-08-24 15:46:05 (
echo hey
echo bye
)
 4520  2019-08-24 16:00:21 history
 4521  2019-08-24 16:00:23 history  | less
```

the output of history broken when lithist broken, too:

```
    1  2019-08-24 14:25:04 \rm .bash_history
    2  2019-08-24 14:25:13 (
    3  2019-08-24 14:42:26 echo a
    4  2019-08-24 14:42:26 echo c
    5  2019-08-24 14:42:26 )
```

however, my history file looked ok:

```
#1566627904
\rm .bash_history
#1566627913
(
echo a
echo c
)
#1566627926
echo bye
```

this behavior appear on CentOS 6.10 , and can not be fix,
but can be fix on another machine with debian stretch.

Comment: I can find no actual question in your message. The type of Linux you are running is (mostly) irrelevant, but it would be good to know the version of `bash` that you are running (when it works and when it does not work). Changes made to particular versions of `bash` (including bug fixes) may be found at https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES  If you think you have found a genuine _bug_ in the shell, there's a `bashbug` command for reporting it.

Comment: the question is why lithist not work. bash in centos6 is 4.1.2(2) , and bash in debian stretch is 4.1.2(1) . i am not sure it is a bug.